# Re-delivery Delay in Solace

Tags: solace

I have plans to implement re-delivery delay, re-delivery counts and dead letter queue using solace.
The idea is, if the message is not ack-ed 5 times, put it to the dead letter queue. However, I want to spread those 5 retries over a span of time.

I didn't see any documentation around re-delivery delay on the solace website.

Did I miss something? Is this feature not there? Or, is there some equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Messages will be redelivered only when the consumer unbinds from the queue, or if you using JMS, when session.recover() is called.

You could implement your own application logic to unbind the consumer after a delay and set the max-redelivery value on the queue to 5.